# How can i make dynamic selecte box in a formula using laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8

The problem is that all of data comme from postgresql data base. The list of second selecte box depende on the first and will be charged from table in data base using foreign keys.

Comment: Please elaborate more, provide some codes or examples if there is and provide more details. Because this question seems to be seeking for a tutorial which is not suitable for Stack Overflow as SO is not a tutorial service or a free code writing service. Askers are expected to show the problems they are facing while attempting this. Goodluck :)

Comment: as @I_love_vegetables mentioned, please take a while and read about how to ask a question in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
and also this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask